# producing flutter (Xcode) testflight archive fails with multiple commands produce

Tags: flutter, testflight

need to produce an archive so we can upload to TestFlight so followed instructions in https://flutter.dev/docs/deployment/ios . my flutter runs on both real iPhone and simulator with no problem. so I produce a release version as required then open the resultant Xcode project (runner). immediately see the error

:-1: Multiple commands produce '/Users/jmcfet/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-cwxykfeiijpirmgbtrkzktdrahbt/ArchiveIntermediates/Runner/InstallationBuildProductsLocation/Applications/Runner.app/Frameworks/Flutter.framework':
1) Target 'Runner' has copy command from '/Users/jmcfet/AndroidStudioProjects/sis/ios/Flutter/Flutter.framework' to '/Users/jmcfet/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-cwxykfeiijpirmgbtrkzktdrahbt/ArchiveIntermediates/Runner/InstallationBuildProductsLocation/Applications/Runner.app/Frameworks/Flutter.framework'
2) That command depends on command in Target 'Runner': script phase “[CP] Embed Pods Frameworks”

now this does not happen when I do the same against the "Flutter Hello world" app so wondering what is messed up in my Flutter app

Comment: This seems to be a pod issue. First run ```pod install``` in your ios folder then run again ```flutter build ios --no-codesign ``` then you can create the archive from Xcode.

Answer (score 0):

no luck :

johns-MacBook-Air:ios jmcfet$ pod install
Analyzing dependencies
Fetching podspec for `Flutter` from `.symlinks/flutter/ios`
Fetching podspec for `video_player` from `.symlinks/plugins/video_player/ios`
Downloading dependencies
Using Flutter (1.0.0)
Using video_player (0.0.1)
Generating Pods project
Integrating client project
Pod installation complete! There are 2 dependencies from the Podfile and 2 total pods installed.

[!] Automatically assigning platform `ios` with version `8.0` on target `Runner` because no platform was specified. Please specify a platform for this target in your Podfile. See `https://guides.cocoapods.org/syntax/podfile.html#platform`.

[!] CocoaPods did not set the base configuration of your project because your project already has a custom config set. In order for CocoaPods integration to work at all, please either set the base configurations of the target `Runner` to `Pods/Target Support Files/Pods-Runner/Pods-Runner.profile.xcconfig` or include the `Pods/Target Support Files/Pods-Runner/Pods-Runner.profile.xcconfig` in your build configuration (`Flutter/Release.xcconfig`).

not an IOS expert but looks like the install was not successful. little confused as the Xcode project was generated by Flutter so why is Flutter generating a bad config file. if so looks like a bug to me

Comment: actually the answer is here:https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/20685

Comment: did it solve the issue?